# Replace countdown with text

Tags: flutter, dart, text, countdown

I wanted to replace my countdown with a Text when it is finished. I have made that with a `List<bool>` and I think my code is good. But it doesn't work and I don't know why... I have a `RenderFlex overflowed by 99966 pixels on the bottom` and the `countdownTimer` isn't replace when it is finished. This renderFlex is not in all items but just sometimes, I really don't understand. I have this issue : `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1`. The renderFlex leave when I click on the button of the item which is above.
This is my code :

**main.dart**

```
class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  List<Item> savedItems = new List<Item>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                onPressed: () => pushToFavorite(context))
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: itemData.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
...
             CountWidget(itemData[index].countdown, index),
...
}
```

**myWidget.dart**

```
class CountWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final int date;
  final int index;
  const CountWidget(this.date, this.index);

  @override
  _CountWidgetState createState() => _CountWidgetState();
}

class _CountWidgetState extends State<CountWidget> {
  List<bool> notFinished = List<bool>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    notFinished.add(true);
    return notFinished.elementAt(widget.index)
        ? Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: CountdownTimer(
                daysSymbol: new Text("j "),
                hoursSymbol: new Text(" : "),
                minSymbol: new Text(" : "),
                secSymbol: new Text(""),
                endTime: widget.date,
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                onEnd: () {
                  setState(() {
                    notFinished[widget.index] =
                        notFinished[widget.index] == false;
                  });
                }))
        : Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
            child: Text('It is Finished', style : TextStyle(fontSize: 14),));
  }
}
```

**What I get when I launch my code**

[image: What I get when I launch my code]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `shrinkWrap: false,` in `ListView.builder()`, Also wrap the all `Text()` widget with `Flexible()`.

Also, a suggestion that rather than doing `notFinished.add(true);`, keep all the add all the values inside a `StreamBuilder()` this will not only make the app more readable but also eliminate the need to setState() in `onEnd()`.

Comment: I doesn't fix my error I have this issue : `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
`

Comment: `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..1: 2
`

Comment: Can you print `itemData.length` and tell me whats the length of the current snapshot?